# SOLR Fuzzy search for part of words

Tags: solr, solr4, solarium

first of all i've no rights to edit the schema because the client uses a hosted solr.

i try to finde the following word:

```
Coagulometerröhrchen
```

with this query:

```
&q=(röhrchen~)&defType=edismax
```

When i try to use the query like this:

```
&q=(*röhrchen*~)&defType=edismax
```

it's missing some keyresults

Is there a way to find the right results with a optimized query?

Solr-Version: 8.11.1

Comment: What kind of processing happens on the field? Wildcard queries won't have most filters applied in the analysis chain, so if you have filters that converts `ö` for example, they might not be applied as expected; also fuzzy searches will be limited to an edit distance of 2 usually - and is applied on the token level (i.e. what is left after analysis).

Comment: @MatsLindh no fancy processing on the field its just the standard title field. Following is written in the schema:                 "name": "title",
                "type": "text",
                "omitNorms": true,
                "termVectors": true,
                "indexed": true,
                "stored": true

Comment: Look at the current schema to get the actual field type and what kind of analysis is attached; for a plain `text_en` field I wouldn't think there'd be any hits against `Coagulometerröhrchen` for `röhrchen~` as the edit distance is too large. You might also want to give `title:` as a prefix (or use `qf`) to actually search against the `title` field, depending on what has been set as a default search field or a default `qf` - since you haven't explicitly given any field to search against.